# How can I do this with loop function?

Tags: r

how can it be done with a for loop or apply family

```
country <- lDataFrames[[1]]
league_name <- lDataFrames[[2]]
goals <- lDataFrames[[3]]
player_name <- lDataFrames[[4]]
```

#this is what i have tried

```
 datanames <- c("country","league_name","goals","player_name")
    for (i in 1:4) {
    assign(datanames[i], lDataFrames[[i]])

}
```

#it is giving me the desired result but with a slight problem. the problem it is giving me that it is only assigning the 11 observations of 2 variables for all the elements. maybe because lDataFrames[[1]] has 11 observations of 2 variables. How can I get all the observations for the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If `lDataFrames` has list of dataframes and you want to separate them out in individual dataframes you could assign names to them and use `list2env`.

```
names(lDataFrames) <- c("country","league_name","goals","player_name")
list2env(lDataFrames, .GlobalEnv)
```